# Issues with automatic update on a rooted Epic 4g touch

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-2

So my phone originally had (before the root) Android 2.3.6. After the root process, it ended with 2.3.4 and it keeps telling me to update. A few things aren't working for me anymore, and I'm not sure if that's because of the root process or because of a bad 2.3.4 version.

Anyway, every couple of days my phone will notify me that there is an update available (likely the 2.3.6 I had before) and it asks if I'd like to restart and install. Upon clicking restart, it goes black, starts an update screen (with a progress bar) and goes about 1/4 the way before it stops updating and shows me a warning sign.

My question(s): Am I able to apply an update via a rooted phone? If so, what might be going wrong? If not, is there a way to either turn off that update (or get it via a different method or something)?

Comment: Sprint is really nice about forcing these updates. I ended up having to unroot my friends phone because he wanted the Evo update so bad. My personal solution you'll find below ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer(s): (these are limited to my experiences)

No, you most likely will not be able to apply a standard update to a rooted phone.

As far as turning off the update, this is most likely specific to the phone, and if it's being pushed by your carrier, my guess is you can't just turn it off. I would choose (now that you're rooted) to just flash a new ROM. If you like your stock stuff, you can probably find a ROM that is the same thing you're using now, with the 2.3.6 update.

[This ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1389721) may be what you're looking for in the case I described. It doesn't require you to do a wipe either, basically the update for your phone!

Comment: I'm considering flashing to an ICS rom, but I don't know if any of them are stable enough for my liking yet, so I decided to just update to 2.3.6 if I could and wait on it a bit.